# How to pass a job object instance to quartz scheduler

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

What I want to be able to do is read a file with a bunch of batch files (and args) and create a quartz job for each of those entries.  I know I'm missing something obvious, but I can't seem to find how to do this anywhere on google.  Everything I'm finding says a new class has to be coded for each job which can't be externally constructed.  I can't seem to find how to create an instance of a class which I can pass into the scheduler.

```
public class MyJob implements Job{
    private String[] jobArgs = null;

    public MyJob(String[] jobArgs){
        this.jobArgs = jobArgs;
    }

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException{
        ExternalProcess ep - new ExternalProcess();
        try{
            ep.runExecutableCommand(jobargs);
        }catch(Exception e){...}
    }

}

public class JobScheduler {
    ...
    List<String[]> jobArgList = loadJobListFromDisk();
    List<MyJob> = new ArrayList<MyJob>();
    for(String[] jobArgs : jobList){
        MyJob myJob = new MyJob(jobArgs);
        // Is it possible to pass in a reference to an instance somehow
        // instead of letting the scheduler create the instance based on
        // the class definition?  I know this syntax doesn't work, but this
        // is the general idea of what I'm trying to do.
        JobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.newJob(myJob).withIdentity...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In quartz 2, you need to use a JobDataMap (stored in the jobDetail) to transfer parameters to the execute method. It will be available in the context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap()

Answer (score 0):

From what ive had quality time with Quartz Scheduler or rather JobBuilder, its written in such a dumb way it only accepts Class object as parameter. I was not able to find a way to pass Job Object into the builder.

It's a very very bad design, resulting in future problems with writing generic solutions for Quartz in version 1.X at least.